# I want to delete a list item using Jquery when I click this red box.. How do I target a grandparent div?

Tags: jquery, class, html, parent, target

When I click the class "red" I want to delete this entire div.  My JS is

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.buttons .red').click(function(){
        $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
    <h3> Keep</h3>
    <div id= "container">
        <a href="categories.html" class="green" data-transition="slide"  data-type="horizontal" data-role="button">Tax Deductible</a>
        <a href="#" class="red" data-transition="slide"  data-type="horizontal" data-role="button">Tax Deductible</a>
        <a href="categories.html" class="blue" data-transition="slide"  data-type="horizontal" data-role="button">Tax Deductible</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which `div`? The  one with the `id` of `container` or the one with the `data-*` attributes? And where are the `.buttons` element(s)?

Comment: the one with data-* attrributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('a[data-role="button"].red').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('div[data-role]').remove();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AVxZS/).

This attaches the click event to an `a` element who has the `data-role` attribute with the value of `button`, and also the class of `red`.

The default behaviour of the `click` event is prevented (to prevent `hashChange`, or page-jumping/loading), the selector moves up the DOM from the `a` element to the first ancestor element with the `data-role` attribute set and removes that element.

The use of `closest()` means you can nest the `a` element inside of other elements (within the same ancestor), and the function will still work (whereas with `parent().parent()...` you'd have to rewrite the jQuery selector *every* time an ancestor was inserted/removed.

References:

- [attribute-equals `[attribute="value"]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('.red').click(function(){


     $(this).parent().parent().remove();

});
});
```

Will work, you only need to delete the grandparent, couse the "parent" is inside grandparent.

Answer (score 0):

Your code probably doesn't work, as you do not have buttons class on page. Also, you don't have to call the second remove, as your first parenting DIV will be deleted along with your collapsible DIV.

Another thing is that you can use an `:eq()` selector if you need to select a grand-parent.

Working code (I only added class buttons to the container div):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.buttons .red').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('div:eq(1)').remove();
        return false;
    });
});​
```

jfFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RxyPk/

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't exits your class buttons.

```
$('.red').click(function(){


console.log($(this).parent('div').parent('div'));


});
```

works